# What's the best practice to do something after a location update?

Tags: android, android-location

This is more of a theoretical question.
I'm using `LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()` for a single location update request and i want to do something with the location. The problem is the update is asynchronous and i don't know when does it finish exactly.
What's the best practice to call something exactly after the location update finishes and never before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LocationListener` in `onLocationChanged`. It seems it's the only place you can do something

Answer (score 1):

So there are 3 types of `requestSingleUpdate()`

1. `requestSingleUpdate(String provider, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)` :
   Parameters -- a listener whose `onLocationChanged(Location)` method will be called when the location update is available and a looper object whose message queue will be used to implement the callback mechanism, or null to make callbacks on the calling thread
2. `requestSingleUpdate(Criteria criteria, LocationListener listener, PendingIntent intent)` :
   If the caller supplied a pending intent, then location updates are sent with a key of KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED and a Location value with the pending intent and `onLocationChanged(Location)` method will be called when the location update is available for listener passed.
3. `public void requestSingleUpdate (Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)` : This is same as ***2*** except `onLocationChanged()` will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing here after location update like:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
        // Do what ever you want here for example here I am showing toast like
            userCurrentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            userCurrentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(this, "you are at: " + userCurrentLatitude + "," + userCurrentLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope that your are using the new fused location provider in android as it is more accurate and power efficient.The activity in which you are implementing fused location provider you will have the method

```
    @Override
public void onReceiveLocation(Location location) 
{
    latitude=location.getLatitude();
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
}
```

do whatever you want to do in this method as this will be called only when the location is recieved or if you are using locationlistner then do the same thing onLocationChanged() method